# Not able to bind value to tooltip using replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have used jQuery `.replaceWith()` to insert new DOM contents. All the contents are getting replaced but the value of title does not bind.

I have tried the below code but the tooltip only shows `{{descriptions.title}}` instead of the text that's supposed to be shown.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.showDescription = function(descriptions) {
            $("#description").find('span#header').replaceWith("<span id='header' class='mleft' title='{{descriptions.title}}'>" + descriptions.name + " - " + descriptions.title + "</span>");
}
```

I expect the tooltip to display descriptions.title value instead of just `{{descriptions.title}}`

Answer (score 2):

You only add the string `{{description.title}}` as your title, you need to add the variable itself:

```
$scope.showDescription = function(descriptions) {
            $("#description").find('span#header').replaceWith("<span id='header' class='mleft' title='" + description.title + "'>" + descriptions.name + " - " + descriptions.title + "</span>");
}
```

Edit: 
A in my opinion better approach would be to not use replaceWith here but just to change the desired attributes:

```
    $scope.showDescription = function(descriptions) {
                $("#description").find('span#header').attr("title",description.title).html(descriptions.name + descriptions.title);
}
```

That way you can change the html itself and don't need to adapt the JS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate it in - that's not an Angular variable, it's just normal JS:

```
$scope.showDescription = function(descriptions) {
    $("#description").find('span#header').replaceWith("<span id='header' class='mleft' title='" + descriptions.title + "'>" + descriptions.name + " - " + descriptions.title + "</span>");
}
```

Or just use template strings (ES6):

```
$scope.showDescription = function(descriptions) {
    $("#description").find('span#header').replaceWith(`<span id='header' class='mleft' title='${descriptions.title}'>${descriptions.name} - ${descriptions.title}</span>`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Its working fine

```
$("#description").find('span#header')
                 .replaceWith("<span id='header' class='mleft' title="+ descriptions.title+">" + descriptions.name + " - " + descriptions.title + "</span>");
```